I am running UBUNTU at the moment in version 23.04, which reached END OF LIFE, how should I update this?
I have done some research but unfortunately everything I've seen has been posted before the END OF LIFE, happening so doesn't help much. I always get a message that tells me it's "impossible to update version" and "An upgrade from 'lunar' to 'noble' is not supported with this tool.". I didn't really want to clean install UBUNTU, so if there is a way to solve this i'd appreacite.

you may find this Ubuntu Official Documentation addresses your question.

Due note the intended and supported upgrade path for 23.04 was to 23.10 (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManticUpgrades) but that path disappeared when 23.10 reached EOL (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/07/17/ubuntu-23-10-mantic-minotaur-reached-end-of-life-on-july-11-2024/) so you missed the supported path (re-install is now expected)

You could try non-destructive re-install (more complex to 24.04 unless you're using a flavor using the calamares installer; you don't specify product details) OR an Debian type of upgrade; but be aware that Debian-style changes are not supported so QA test your upgrade yourself first (given you left it too late for the supported path; your upgrade path was still open AFTER EOL, at least until the next release 23.10 itself reached EOL)
